# Why are all webkit browsers ignoring my z-index?

Tags: html, css

I have stripped away everything from my webpage so that it is as minimal as necessary to reproduce this issue.

---

HTML:

```
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />

        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

        <title>Home | Hmmm</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Shared/Assets/Stylesheets/Core.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/Shared/Assets/Stylesheets/Home.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <img id="key" src="~/Shared/Assets/Images/Icons/K.png" alt="Sign In | Create an Account" />
            <img id="logo" src="~/Shared/Assets/Images/Logos/JWLSS.png" alt="Hmmm" />
        </header>
        <div id="main">
            <footer>
                <p style="margin-top: 100px; text-align: center; color: white;">&copy; Hmmm 2015</p>
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    outline: none;
    outline: 0;
    border: none;
    border: 0;

    font-family: 'Segoe UI Light', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

html, body
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;

    background-image: url('../Images/Backgrounds/JWSSB.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

    background-position-y: 50%;
}

header
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 50%;

    background-color: #2695D7;

    opacity: 0.90;
}

#main
{
    height: 50%;
    background-color: white;
    opacity: 0.90;

    border-top: 0.1px solid white;
    padding-top: 5%;

    position: relative;
}

#key
{
    float: right;
}

#logo
{
    text-align: center;

    margin: 0 auto;

    position: absolute;
    right: calc(100% / 2 - 176px / 2);
    bottom: calc(100% / 2 - 100px / 2);

    z-index: 1000;
}

#sections
{
    width: 50%;
    height: auto;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.section
{
    width: calc(100% / 3);
    height: auto;
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 10pt;
}
```

---

The problem is that the middle logo should be above *everything* but it is not.The bottom half of the logo is beneath the bottom (white) section (#main). Except in Internet Explorer and Microsoft Edge. In all Gecko and WebKit-based browsers, the z-index property is being ignored on the #logo element.

I have tried numerous things based on what I thought was wrong, and based on what I've found in my research while trying to find a solution.

I've read that in webkit browsers, z-index is ignored if the parent elements do not explicitely specify `position`. So I added `position: relative;` to the parents. This didn't change anything.

I've also read that FireFox (specifically), ignores the z-index if an element is using a negative value - this does not apply to me.

I don't know what else to do. And I've never encountered this problem before.

How do I get my absolutely-positioned logo to appear *above* **everything**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increase the position for header element.

```
header{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 99999;
}
```

Because of [stacking order](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context), you cannot position the logo above the header as in your case header and main element has same stacking order, that's why you need to increase the stacking order for header than other elements such as if your main is set to 1 then set header to 2 then only your header will be in upper layer than main layer.

Hope you understand!

The best way to use your header element inside main element so that you can easily maintain the z-index.

But I agree, semantically this is not good idea.

Comment: Thank you. I could have sworn that I read ages ago that elements are automatically assigned a z-index based on the order they appear in the document?

Comment: I can't use that. When I use your code, it pushes the logo up to the top of the page and screws up my centering code. Not sure why :-/

Comment: You should re-css if you use like that. But , the best way to use your header element inside main element so that you can easily maintain the z-index.

Answer (score 1):

The logo is in the header, and the header is not in the layer stack. You need to positioning relative the header and give it a z-index. The other element in header that's not the logo will be in the same z-index as well.

Answer (score 0):

For webkit browsers like Safari, you want to additionally use `transform: translate3d(0,0,0);` on the `relative` positioned elements.

Don't ask me why this is so.. I had HUGE STRUGGLES with this.

Here some pre-fixes: for transform

```
-ms-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0); /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
```

Loot at following page: www.meineluftaufnahme.de

I once had to use `transform` there. If you look at the css, I use it only on the `position: relative;` elements.

Comment: display: relative? and what the shit use of translate3d here in regards to OP question?

Comment: This is a mistaken answer.Maybe in some cases the transform solves you a problem, but it is not the case. `Display:relative` is an unexisting value, relative is position.

Comment: Thanks Marcos, I corrected it to `position`. @Bhojendra: This is not shit. Shit is when you code a website and the page looks like shit inside Safari, because `z-index` is not working like intended. `transform` on `position: relative` elements will fix it. You will thank me if you come to this point and don't have to search for an answer for hours/days/weeks.

Comment: @CagatayUlubay Then, I will wait for the problem like that would come soon over me.